# Call Java function in XSLT

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I have case study of using java call method in xslt.

Below is my XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:test="java:com.package_name.com.Test">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/" >
    <xsl:for-each select="info/data">
      <xsl:variable name="VALUE" select="number"/>
      <int>
         <xsl:value-of select="test:calculate($VALUE)"/>
      </int>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Java function:

```java
public static String calculate(int n) {
    String message="The NUmber is Right";
    String error="Wrongggg";
    if (n == 5) 
       return (message);
    else
       return (error);
}
```

I am getting error message as follows:

```
Type:INTEGER:5
                                    Text:CHARACTER:Transformation failure when processing Stylesheet deployed:./Test.xsl
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The XSL processor reported a possibly fatal error.
Message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1017)
    at com.ibm.xsl.exmlt.StylesheetCache.preprocessStylesheet(StylesheetCache.java:763)
    at com.ibm.xsl.exmlt.StylesheetCache.getPreprocessedStylesheet(StylesheetCache.java:686)
    at com.ibm.xsl.exmlt.StylesheetSelector.getTransformer(StylesheetSelector.java:372)
    at com.ibm.xsl.exmlt.StylesheetSelector.performSelection(StylesheetSelector.java:681)
    at com.ibm.xsl.exmlt.EnhancedXMLTransform.transformDocument(EnhancedXMLTransform.java:615)
    at com.ibm.xsl.mqsi.XMLTransformData.transformData(XMLTransformData.java:555)
    at com.ibm.xsl.mqsi.XMLTransformNode.evaluate(XMLTransformNode.java:965)
    at com.ibm.broker.plugin.MbNode.evaluate(MbNode.java:1480)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: The XSL processor reported a possibly fatal error.
Message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
    at com.ibm.xsl.exmlt.StylesheetSelector.fatalError(StylesheetSelector.java:1725)
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.newTemplates(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:1009)
```

Can any one correct me how to call java function inside XSLT.

Comment: Can you show us the signature of the `calculate` method, which arguments does it expect, which Java types do they have?

Comment: It all depends on which XSLT processor you are using: you need to tell us. (Ah, from the depths of the stack trace, it looks like Xalan. I have added a tag.)

Comment: the calulate method is nothing,,,just simple if else statement @MartinHonnen

Comment: @rohit31dec91, we need to see the definition of the number and of the types of arguments the `calcuate` method has so please edit your question and show that information.

Comment: @MartinHonnen i have added the calulate function of java. See if u can correct me in some ways.

Comment: Does `<xsl:value-of select="test:calculate(number($VALUE))"/>` work?